# How to use params as part of Postmapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, annotations

in the below code, i am trying to practice how to use params. in postman i used the following

```
    http://localhost:8080/root/doStuff3/8
```

but it does not work.
please let me know how to use params given the below code.

**code**

```
@PostMapping("/doStuff3", params = arrayOf("id = 9"))
@ResponseBody
fun doStuff3(@RequestParam id : String) : String {
    return "doStuff3_" + id
}
```

**postman**:

```
http://localhost:8080/root/doStuff3/8
```

Comment: What you have there (/8) is not a request parameter. It's a path variable. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this for request param(query type).

> http://localhost:8080/root/doStuff3?id=someId

As JB Nizet Sir suggested doStuff3/8 is a path variable not a request param.
In the PostMan client, you have to directly paste the url and select the method type as POST.